# How to add Combo Feature in a ContainerShape Graphiti

Tags: eclipse-emf, draw2d, eclipse-gmf, graphiti

I want to add a drop down combo box filter inside a container in the Graphiti Editor.

It appears if I override this  method:

```
public IDirectEditingFeature getDirectEditingFeature(IDirectEditingContext context)
```

...as shown in the figure below:

[image]

...but my requirement is not to bring the drop down feature on clicking over the region, but a stable combo control on the Shape/Container as shown below:

[image]

Is there any way in Graphiti to add such controls on Shape?

Comment: have you found a solution?

Comment: The solution was only to add some icon and feature over it and when the click is done the combo will appear.